# Length of a job search

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have been looking for a front end web development role in the UK from another country.  I have been searching for a full month already, I've sent about 30 CVs, had 2 Skype interviews - for the 1st I didn't have enough knowledge, for 2nd I didn't have a college degree. I have about 2 years of experience and I'm permitted to work in the UK.

Is this normal? What's the typical job searching time from abroad?

Comment: Not sure how we can define a normal time frame for this.

Comment: Are you in the EU or outside the EU?

Answer (score 6):

Searching from abroad is really difficult, mainly because the employer has a lot of responsibilities when hiring someone from abroad.

This could include

- Sponsoring the Employee
- Confirming your eligibility to work in the country
- Trusting that the time they spend training you into their business is going to be worthwhile in the long run.

That being said, job hunting for a month is pretty normal even when you're physically in the country, I've normally spent at least a month, and it's not uncommon to spend three months job hunting.

Something that can really really help is getting ahold of a really good recruiter.  This can be hard, but try reaching out to a few on Linked in.

Comment: Personally I really like C2B in Dunstable,  @C2BSolutionsuk (www.c2bsolutions.co.uk)  I came over from New Zealand, and they got me my first job here in England.

Answer (score 2):

Note that one of the reasons standard advice is that your emergency fund be enough to carry you for 3-6 months is that a job hunt can be expected to take that long. You may get lucky and land something earlier, but don't count on it, even without the international issue.

The odds of a web designer being hired across international borders without a college degree are probably not good. There are too many college grads who are willing to consider that as their first job, and who can be interviewed more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I've very recently found a new job in in England from Japan. Realistically, a time frame just isn't possible. This entirely depends on your abilities, experience and ultimately showing you're a good fit for the company.

I was very fortunate in my find. Just show commitment as well as showing you're capable of doing the job.

To give some insight, it took me a month, but in this time I sent my CV to 100+ agencies and companies, had 7+ interviews and for the job I got, had to fly to England for 1 day to spend with the company (from Japan, which wasn't fun). I also had endless calls from 3rd parties that got me a couple of extra interviews.

I was also working my current job during all of this.

From an industry perspective, Front-end developers have it really tough. You have to have a shiny portfolio, Github activity, all sorts just to get your foot in the door for an interview. Finding a role Front-end development overseas especially entry-level is a ball busting exercise. With 2-years experience, unless you have exceptional abilities, try to look at entry-level stuff and make sure you have a very nice portfolio to show off.

Answer (score 0):

I graduated from a top 10 engineering school (U.S.) with a Computer Science degree and a 3.0 GPA. It took me 20+ job applications (all entry level) before I even got an interview.

Out of the 25 or so companies I applied to, only 3 ever got back to me. I had no related experience, which is my best guess as to why I didn't hear back.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking in major cities where there is likely to be a lot of competition, then it could take a while. Also, Development markets in the UK are pretty competitive, especially in the junior ranks so yes it can take a while. Maybe consider spreading your search to smaller towns too, as well as large cities as jobs further afield tend to have less applicants.